# how to filter with join using mysql?

Tags: mysql

Using MySQL 8.0:
Here's my code:

```
WITH table1 AS (
SELECT MAX(CASE 
    WHEN a.A IS NULL THEN 4
    WHEN b.code IS NULL THEN 3
    ELSE a.A
    END  
) AS CODE,
    CASE 
        WHEN a.A IS NULL THEN 'BLANK' 
        WHEN b.code IS NULL THEN 'NOT VALID'
        ELSE b.description 
    END AS SEX,
COUNT(*) AS TOTAL ,
ROUND(100.0 * COUNT(*) / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (), 2) AS PERCENT
FROM AA a LEFT JOIN BB b ON b.code = a.A where a.type = 1
GROUP BY SEX
)
SELECT CODE, SEX, TOTAL, PERCENT, 
    SUM(TOTAL) OVER (ORDER BY CODE) AS CUMULATIVE, 
    ROUND(100.0 * SUM(TOTAL) OVER (ORDER BY CODE) / SUM(TOTAL) OVER (), 2) AS CUMPERCENT
FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT 0, 'TOTAL', COUNT(*), 100.00, 0, 0.00
FROM AA
ORDER BY CODE;
```

```
CODE | SEX        | TOTAL | PERCENT | CUMULATIVE | CUMPERCENT
0      TOTAL        11      100.00    0            0.00
1      Male         2       33.33     2            33.33
2      Female       2       33.33     4            66.67
3      NOT VALID    1       16.67     5            83.33
4      BLANK        1       16.67     6            100.00
```

Desired output:

```
CODE | SEX        | TOTAL | PERCENT | CUMULATIVE | CUMPERCENT
0      TOTAL        6       100.00    0            0.00
1      Male         2       33.33     2            33.33
2      Female       2       33.33     4            66.67
3      NOT VALID    1       16.67     5            83.33
4      BLANK        1       16.67     6            100.00
```

The problem is The total should be 6. How will I filter items with type = 1 only in table AA?

Here's my sample [database](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jYQJPV1X1XPbLp72LqA5CZ/5):

```
CREATE TABLE AA (
    A int,
    type int
);

insert into AA (A,type) values (1,1);
insert into AA (A,type) values (1,1);
insert into AA (A,type) values (2,1);
insert into AA (A,type) values (2,1);
insert into AA (A,type) values (3,1);
insert into AA (A,type) values (NULL,1);
insert into AA (A,type) values (1,2);
insert into AA (A,type) values (1,2);
insert into AA (A,type) values (1,2);
insert into AA (A,type) values (2,2);
insert into AA (A,type) values (2,2);

CREATE TABLE BB (
    code int,
    description varchar(30)
);

insert into BB (code, description) values (1, 'Male');
insert into BB (code, description) values (2, 'Female');
```

THANK YOU.

Comment: Please add the desired output

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to add a "total"-row depending on the content of your cte, you can just reuse it:

```
UNION ALL
SELECT 0, 'TOTAL', SUM(TOTAL), 100.00, 0, 0.00
FROM table1
ORDER BY CODE;
```

sums the totals of the rows of `table1` (which are the rows with code 1 to 4 and thus the rows you are showing).

If you, as stated, actually want to filter `AA` directly, to get and count the same rows as in your cte, you have to redo the filter you did in your cte:

```
UNION ALL
SELECT 0, 'TOTAL', COUNT(*), 100.00, 0, 0.00
FROM AA a LEFT JOIN BB b ON b.code = a.A where a.type = 1
ORDER BY CODE;
```

This requires MySQL to evaluate this a second time though, so you may not actually want to do that.